# How to deploy Docker image from AWS ECR to Amazon Elastic Beanstalk using Github Actions (yml)?

Tags: docker, next.js, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, github-actions, cicd

I'm working on Next.js + TS + AWS stack (ECR as image container + Elastic Beanstalk as hosting) + Github Actions.

`.github/workflows/ci-cd.yml` file has been created with the following steps:

- checkout code + set up node.js (works)
- AWS credentials + login to ECR + build/push image to ECR (works)

The issue I have currently is with deploying created image on ECR to AWS Elastic Beanstalk.
**How should the deploy code part in Github workflow *.yml file look like to meet the requirements of using created Docker image and pushing it to Elastic Beanstalk.** Deployment is successful (new application version information appears) but content doesn't update, hence I assume image deploy part is missing. Any examples of proper implementation?

Do I need `Dockerrun.aws.json` files or/and utilize S3 / zip deployment package?
My understanding is that created image on container is already an artifact ready to be used.

I've tried multiple options similar to code below:

```
   - name: Deploy to Elastic Beanstalk
        run: |
          # Get the ECR image URI
          ECR_REGISTRY="${{ steps.login-ecr.outputs.registry }}"
          ECR_REPOSITORY=<my_repository_name>
          IMAGE_TAG="${{ github.sha }}"
          ECR_IMAGE_URI="$ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:$IMAGE_TAG"

          # Modify the version label to replace slashes with underscores
          VERSION_LABEL=$(echo "$ECR_IMAGE_URI" | tr '/' '_')

          # Create application version using the ECR image URI
          aws elasticbeanstalk create-application-version \
            --application-name <my_app_name> \
            --version-label $VERSION_LABEL \

          # Update environment to use the new application version
          aws elasticbeanstalk update-environment \
            --environment-name <my_environment_name> \
            --version-label $VERSION_LABEL
```